# How to save custom value in DB from custom .module

Tags: 7

I have *inherited* a custom module, which groups together some field of an custom ContentType and sends it by email.

In the module there are 3 functions.

Email check preg match:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
  require_once($class_name . '.lib.php');
}
require_once('vumclass.lib.php');
```

This function gets triggered when the node is saved or updated. Right?

```
function vumveranstaltungsmailer_action_info() {
  return array(
    'vumveranstaltungsmailer_action' => array(
      'type' => 'node',
      'label' => 'vumveranstaltungsmailer_action',
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers' => array('node_insert', 'node_update'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Do stuff, send email:

```
function vumveranstaltungsmailer_action($object, $context) {
//do Stuff, sends email. Not shown here.

//I want to set this field to empty/clear it
$object->field_email_mailer_01['und']['0']['value']->set(NULL);

}
```

Bare with me, I am pretty a beginner/noob. I am a bit overwhelmed where and how to do it. Please give me a simple solution, so I understand it. Quick and dirty is fine for me ;-)

Comment: so you want to change the field value after sending the email ?

Comment: Yes, because I need the field value as the recipient.

Comment: ok I will answer pls check the answer

Comment: are all the fields from the same node or from different can u elaborate on that part?

Comment: Yes, all the fields are from the same node/CT.



`    function vumveranstaltungsmailer_action($object, $context) {
    dsm($object, '$object');
      if ($object->type === 'veranstaltung' && $object->status === 1 && isset($object->field_email_mailer_01['und']['0']['value'])) {
    //do Stuff, sends email. Not shown here.

    //I want to set this field to empty/clear it
$object->field_email_mailer_01['und']['0']['value']->set(NULL);

    }
    }
`

Comment: can u get the node id if yes then its simple?

Comment: pls check the  answer and let me know if you need any help

Comment: Yes, I have $object->nid;

Comment: check the answer..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11480/discussion-between-harshal-and-whitefleach)

Comment: pls move to chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get your nid of the node you can use the code below to change the field value

```
  $node = node_load($nid);

   unset($node->field_example['und'][0]['value']);
    //similarly for other fields you can change the value
    node_save($node);
```